# How to reset Recyclerview's item view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am having an `ImageView` and a `FrameLayout` placed above it in the `RecyclerView` item. The `FrameLayout`'s visibility is set to INVISIBLE by default.
I am loading `ImageView`'s image through a URL using Volley library. I want to show the `Framelayout` i.e. `FrameLayout`'s visibility should be set to visible only when the image is loaded successfully and not before it. I have implemented listener to listen to the image loading which set the `FrameLayout`'s visibility to visible once image is loaded. But the problem is as `RecyclerView` recycles view, I am getting some `FrameLayout`'s visibility as VISIBLE even if the `ImageView` isn't loaded.

Here is my `onBindViewHolder` code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolderBoxOffice holder, int position)
{
    holder.topContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder.bottomContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    String poster = "some image url";

    holder.mThumbnail.setImageUrl(poster, volleySingleton.getImageLoader());

    /* Listener for listening to image loading*/
    holder.mThumbnail.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View view, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4, int arg5, int arg6, int arg7,
                int arg8)
        {
            if(holder.mThumbnail.getDrawable()!=null)
            {
                holder.topContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.bottomContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                holder.topContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                holder.bottomContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```